# Chrome Kiosk mode ignores zoom settings

Tags: linux, google-chrome, zooming, kiosk

I have a simple shell script that starts chromium in kiosk mode on a certain url.  It works fine, but in kiosk mode the zoom level from Chrome's settings seems to be ignored.

I could normally use ctrl + or ctrl - to zoom in or out, but this is obviously not an option if the browser is run from the script without "human help"

Because of a low screen resolution, It is zoomed in too much by default.  I tried the Chrome Autozoom extension, but for some reason this made it zoom *out* way too much (and it didn't matter at which zoom level I set the extension).

All I want is to be able to specify the zoom level when I start the browser in Kiosk mode.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have this same setup [ linux kiosk running chrome in kiosk mode ] but I haven't seen this.
You can set the default zoom settings in Chrome:

http://fartersoft.com/blog/2010/11/12/setting-a-default-zoom-level-for-chrome-browser/

Are you syncing home directories and possibly overwriting chrome's settings directory? There must be some mechanism in your setup overwriting settings --- or possibly it's a permissions issue. Be sure to setup Chrome the way you want --- make sure the settings stick --- before enabling your privacy/security settings and scripts.

If chrome can't write to it's config directory, or, if that directory is getting overwritten your settings will not be preserved --- otherwise, a kiosk like you describe should work with the settings you specify. As I said, we have kiosks setup this way with default zoom settings for touchscreens with low resolutions.

Have any other info on your setup that might affect this issue?

Comment: I saved the settings to a seperate folder and overwrite the current ones from that directory at every startup.  I do this because if chrome closed unexpectedly, it will have some error message at the top when it starts the next time  - and I want to avoid this.  For some reason when chrome starts it still chooses a default zoom level though, and changes its own settings to reflect this.

Comment: What we do is make all the changes to Chrome we need -- so settings are now in home directory. Next we copy the home directory to opt. Lastly, a session script is created which syncs the opt version to home at each login, thus overwriting any changes. Our settings are preserved ...don't get errors. Is it a 'singletonlock error' by chance?

Comment: Also, we don't use any plugins for zoom -- just instructions I posted above.

Comment: If you are getting an error message about singletonlocks, then you probably copied the directory while chrome was running. Another thing you could do ( hackish and avoids the root problem ) is throw a find statement in your login script that checks for the singletonlock directory and deletes it if found.

Comment: I'll mark your answer as correct since it contains useful information, and this post is now old.  Somewhere during my fiddlings I seemed to have fixed the problem.